# (Python) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Tags: python, list, recursion, sudoku, indices

This is some code taken out of a Sudoku solver that I'm working on. I changed a bit of it to shrink it down but the fundamental issue of it is still there. If I were to run this, it would go through the `solve` function one time but then upon returning to the `board[x][y] += 1` part of the `add1` function, it returns `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`. I can't find any answers. Can't figure out why a list is being passed instead of just numbers. Please help!

```
def init_board():
    board = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    for i in board:
        for x in range(0,9):
            i.append(0)
    return board

def add1(x, y):
    board[x][y] += 1

def solve(row, column):
    add1(row, column)
    for row in board:
        print(row)
    if True:
        if row == 8 and column == 8:
            return
        if column == 8:
            row += 1
            column = 0
        if column < 8:
            column += 1
        solve(row, column)

board = init_board()

solve(0,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you put `for row in board:` you are iterating through `board` (a list of lists) and setting `row` to each inner list. Subsequently when you call `solve(row, column)`, you are passing in `row`, which is now a list.

If that is not what you intended, change `row` in `for row in board:` to a different variable name so it doesn't clash with your existing int variable `row`.